# varchar to datatime conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do this

```
declare @slice VARCHAR = '2013-06-04 13:42:41.647'
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@slice AS DATETIME), 109), ' ', '-')
```

but I get error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If I do

```
declare @slice3 VARCHAR = '2013-06-04 13:42:41.647'
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @slice3 , 109), ' ', '-')
```

The output I get is 2

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined a `varchar` variable with no length.  Try this:

```
declare @slice VARCHAR(255) = '2013-06-04 13:42:41.647'
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CAST(@slice AS DATETIME), 109), ' ', '-')
```

Note that the length is only really needed for the `declare`.  For some reason, SQL Server defaults a `varchar` and `nvarchar` with no length to 1 character in a declare, but to 30 characters in `convert()`.

You can see really clearly what happens if you do:

```
declare @slice VARCHAR = '2013-06-04 13:42:41.647';
select @slice; -- or print @slice, if you like
```

Comment: Thank you. Really I did not notice that